# can 32 byte shared secret can be given as input to HKDF-SHA512?

Tags: key-derivation

since digest size of sha512 is 512 bits or 64 bytes , is it safe to use values lower than 64 bytes as input to hkdf?
I learned than hkdf uses hmac internally and input for hmac-512 is recommended to be equal to digest size that is 64 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

For `HKDF-Extract`, the input keying material (IKM) gets fed into the HMAC message rather than the key, and there's no mention of a specific IKM size in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869#section-2.2). However, using 256 bits of IKM is wise because smaller keys generally shouldn't be used anymore.

By contrast, the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869#section-2.3) states that the pseudorandom key (PRK) for `HKDF-Expand` should be at least as long as the hash length. This is presumably said to discourage a potential reduction in security. However, a 256 bit key is considered enough in all cases, with 512 bits being practically speaking overkill.

The PRK will be 512 bits anyway with HKDF-SHA512 if you call `HKDF-Extract` first or a `DeriveKey` function that performs both `HKDF-Extract` then `HKDF-Expand`.

With a shared secret, it's important to call `HKDF-Extract` first because the shared secret won't be uniformly random. With a uniformly random key (e.g. the output of a [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)), you can skip the `HKDF-Extract` step and just do `HKDF-Expand`.

Answer (score 0):

The keyspace of the output will be $\min(2^n,2^{512})$ for an input with $n$ bits of entropy.

A 32-byte (256-bit) random input will result in an output with a keyspace of $2^{256}$, which is plenty.